# How to register custom cell renderer in pe:sheet?

Tags: jsf, handsontable, custom-renderer, primefaces-extensions

I am using the sheet extension of the PrimeFaces Extensions and I would like to register custom cell renderer.

According to the underlying handsontable.js component this is possible with the following code :

```
Handsontable.renderers.registerRenderer('marker-renderer', function(){ //my renderer implementation});
Handsontable.cellTypes.registerCellType('marker', {
    editor: Handsontable.editors.TextEditor,
    renderer: 'marker-renderer',
});
```

Afterwards I try setting the colType property on the pe:sheetcolumn, but the renderer is not taken into account.

Before I registered the cellType there was an error being thrown that cell of type marker is not defined. But now I get no error, but the renderer is not being invoked.